# Replace number at end of each sequence

Tags: java, regex

I have a string that has a sequence of id:status. Status is 0, 1 or 2. I am looking for a way to replace the status' with a new one.

For example:

```
String topicStatusString = "1234:0,567:1,89:2";
String someId = "1234";
topicStatusString.replaceAll(someId+":0", someId+":1");
topicStatusString.replaceAll(someId+":2", someId+":1");
```

As you can see, I have to do two replace's to make sure that the correct status is set for the id. This not only is not efficient, say there is an id 11234, this would change that status as well.

What would the regex look like to make sure it only matches the exact id and one statement to replace the status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a character class `[02]` to match `0` or `2`, and a word boundary `\b` so that `1234:2` could be matched and `11234:2` could not:

```
topicStatusString = topicStatusString.replaceAll("\\b" + someId+":[02]\\b", someId+":1");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hI2zC5/1) here.

If you have digits in `someId`, you do not need to use `Pattern.quote`, but it is a good idea in other scenarios.

Comment: How would I get the status of a given id?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the word-boundary marker (\b) and the match-any (.) Regular Expression features to make replaceAll() do what you need.  For example:

```
public class r1 {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        String topicStatusString = "1234:0,567:1,89:2,11234:2";
        String someId = "1234";
        String regex = "\\b" + someId + ":.";
        String result =
            topicStatusString.replaceAll(regex, someId + ":1");
        System.out.println(topicStatusString);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Results:

```
1234:0,567:1,89:2,11234:2
1234:1,567:1,89:2,11234:2
```